# can we import a wasm module in another wasm module?

Tags: import, module, webassembly

in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Understanding_the_text_format#importing_functions_from_javascript
explains that we can import javascript functions in wasm. how can we import wasm functions in another wasm? i mean imagine i have two wasm modules : A and B. i want call a function in module A in module B. so i need to import it. how can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is not possible today, it is currently being worked in via a proposal known as [Module Linking](https://github.com/WebAssembly/module-linking) (see the [explainer](https://github.com/WebAssembly/module-linking/blob/master/proposals/module-linking/Explainer.md) for more background.) At the time of this posting, this feature is in the early [proposal phase](https://github.com/WebAssembly/proposals), in part because it is dependant on a few other features to land first.